# why webdriver-update command not found although protractor is installed ?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, ubuntu-16.04

why webdriver-update command not found although protractor is installed ?

i installed protractor node as

```
sudo npm install protractor -g
```

and when i try to make

```
sudo webdriver-manager update
```

it return with

```
sudo: webdriver-manager: command not found
```

i tried also to install it manually but i failed to do.

```
tamer@tamer-Inspiron-N5110:/media/tamer/Work/conFusion/test$ protractor protractor.conf.js
[15:23:48] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[15:23:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:23:48] E/direct - Error code: 135
[15:23:48] E/direct - Error message: Could not find chromedriver at /home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
[15:23:48] E/direct - Error: Could not find chromedriver at /home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:65:27)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:198:43)
    at /home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:277:30
    at _fulfilled (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/tamer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
[15:23:48] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
tamer@tamer-Inspiron-N5110:/media/tamer/Work/conFusion/test$ sudo webdriver-manager update
[sudo] password for tamer: 
sudo: webdriver-manager: command not found
```

Comment: is it chromedriver it can't find?

Comment: @Maccurt yes i'm trying to run end-to-end test through chrome

Comment: @TamerHussien .. did the below solution work?

Comment: @AdityaReddy sorry but it didn't work with me

Comment: The second one should work right .. as its invoking the node script directly .. what error are you seeing?

Comment: @AdityaReddy the update is ran ok ... but when i examine the end-to-end test it chrome driver couldn't be found.

Comment: did you do a global update - `node webdriver-manager -g update` as your code looks like its referring the global installation

Comment: @AdityaReddy i do it but it gives me EACCES error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root Causes of your issue might Node REPL unable to pick up the installed node_module

Can you try one of below and see

1. In order to make modules available to the Node.js REPL, it might be useful to add `<</usr/lib>>/node_modules` folder to the `$NODE_PATH` environment variable. 
   [Refer here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more info
2. Goto `.\node_modules\protractor\bin` and execute the `webdriver-manager` trigger script directly.

   `node webdriver-manager update`